# How to get PageName by Group for a Tablix with multiple groups

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

In Microsoft SQL report, multiple groups can exist in one Tablix. PageName can be defined for each group. But when referencing PageName in Page header or footer, Globals!PageName is only way I know of. Question is how I may reference PageName defined in a given group?

Comment: The PageName is used to name a worksheet when exporting to Excel. Why would you reference it inside the report?

Comment: I want to show "Grouped on" value for groups in page header and footer. For example, a Tablix has group SaleTerritory and sub group SaleCountry. Page break is on both SaleTerritory and SaleCountry. In page header, the report is required to show SaleTerritory. And SaleCountry is shown in page footer. The field value for SaleTerritory and SaleCountry cannot be referenced directly in page header and footer. PageName in Group is a way to pass the value.

Comment: So what does `Globals!PageName` show when used in a TextBox in the page header or footer?

Comment: What is shown depends on page breaking on which group. For example, when there is a new SaleTerritory (outer group) value, Globals!PageName will show SaleTerritory for both Header and Footer. And when breaking on SaleCountry, both Header and Footer show SaleCountry. I would like to no matter breaking at which group, Header always shows SaleTerritory and Footer shows SaleCountry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not already done, use page breaks accordingly and set the expression of a group-level TextBox (cell in the Tablix) to contain the value that you want to be displayed in the page header or footer.

Then, in a textbox in the header or footer, reference that textbox in an expression like this:

```
=ReportItems!NameOfTextBox.Value
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. Nice to know that ReportItems can be referenced in page header and footer.